# WordPress - Shortcode for Custom Post Type Category

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

Hej, i want to Display all Posts from one Category of my Custom Post Type with a Shortcode.

Example:

My-Custom-Post-Type:
Tomatoe, Lettuce, Fruit, Vegan, Medium Rare, Rare

Food-category: 
Burger, Pizza, Salad

Burger: 
Vegan, Medium Rare, Rare

Salad: 
Tomatoe, Lettuce, Fruit

Is there a way to do this?
Sorry for bad Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example I think you have confused CPTs with Taxonomies and Terms, but in general all you have to do is first create a custom [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) by adding this in your functions.php:

```
function your_custom_function ( $atts ) {

//Run your Query

//Iterate and display output

return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'your_shortcode', 'your_custom_function' );
```

Then inside your function you would need a [query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to get and display the posts you want, example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'    => 'date',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'cat'        => 3,
    ),
);
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    echo '<li'> . the_title() . '</li>'; 
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

[This tool](https://generatewp.com/wp_query/) can also help you with your custom query.

Comment: If i made Custom categories. Is there a Possible way to print out all posts from this category as example: in category burger are 5 Posts. i want only those 5 to print out. and shortcode something like [My-custom-Post-type food-category="Burger"]

Comment: Yes of course, your questions are answered in the two links I posted in my answer. Check them out, there are examples there.